# Could stack exchange integrate simple image editor?

Tags: feature-request, images, uploader

It would be nice to have simple image editor when posting something.

This would be particularly useful on sites like "Ask Different" or "Physics" where the person that is answering would like to point something on the image, or screenshot.

Comment: [There's an app for that](http://stackapps.com/q/2177/11301)

Comment: @Kevin -1 plagiarism - no quotes ;)

Answer (score 7):

We all have paint (or the non windows equivalent) on our computers already and I cannot imagine that a stack exchange editor would be better than that.

As such this would just be using development time to replicate something that we all already have on our computers

Comment: Well. There are stack exchange sites, that answer is frequently screenshot with arrows that points to the menu items. If think there is a need for simple integrated tool.

Comment: Right, but why would an integrated editor be better that paint? Presumably it was copy pasted into an image program anyway to save the screenshot

Comment: Because it would be faster. It is tedious task (at least to me) to do screenshot, paste screenshot to editor, edit screenshot, export screenshot with editions, upload screenshot.

Comment: To be fair, it took me a little time to track down an Ubuntu equivalent of paint back when I needed to doodle on screenshots. (I eventually found http://askubuntu.com/questions/36577/is-there-a-program-like-microsoft-paint.) Having one built in to StackOverflow would've been more convenient for me. So I don't think this proposal is entirely worthless.

Comment: @Mark yes, because GIMP is so hard to know about that I have to track down a photo editor.

Comment: @Cole: For some uses (like this), you don't need something as fully-featured as GIMP, and you'd instead want a minimalistic application like Paint.

Comment: @ColeJohnson GIMP is a horrible tool for this kind of task if you don't already know how to use it (I don't). For starters, it takes longer just to *launch* GIMP on my (fast) machine than it does to add a quick bit of labelling to a screenshot with Pinta. Simple tasks like drawing circles seem like they are fiddly multi-step processes in GIMP, too (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1086589). The fact that Pinta even exists indicates that there are other people like me who want a moron-friendly image-doodler.

Comment: @MarkAmery The fact that people here don't agree *which* of Ubuntu's image editors is best for the task highlights Richard's point; This stuff is already very available on every major OS. As for the "findability" of Pinta, it's the second result in the official software center when I search "image editor", among more than a page of results. How would an SE image editor add value?

Comment: Plus, there's the stackExchange MultiCollider SuperDropDown Freehand Circle generator!

Comment: @GenericHolidayName I pretty much agree - I'm not going so far as to suggest actually implementing this. But if it were implemented, I would have used it and it would have saved me a few minutes (which is what, in reality, it took me to find and decide on using Pinta). That's all I'm saying.

Comment: @MarkAmery I was being slightly sarcastic. I know it takes forever to load. However, if you use it a lot, you can set your machine up to load GIMP on bootup. There's gotta be a patch that you would compile in that would hide the load screen if it's launched on bootup.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in [Richard Tingle's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/220332/richard-tingle) [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214581/231717) an image editor is available on most operating systems. Additionally the dialog SO offers for uploading images is very convenient, and also tools exist for screenshot sharing like [this one](http://gethyperdesktop.com/) (first found via google). Therefore, I also think there is really no need for such a feature.

Answer (score 1):

[There's an app for that](https://stackapps.com/q/2177/11301)

<sub>Caveat emptor, not sure if it's still in working order</sub>